# Cross-browser text-stroke methods?

Tags: css, sifr, cufon

Wanting to use the new [text-stroke](http://webkit.org/blog/85/introducing-text-stroke/) css attribute on some fonts, but as of this moment, only webkit has support for it.

**Are there any cross-browser compatible methods of applying text-stroke?**

I have been looking into javascript solutions such as [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) and there seems to be a feature request put in for supporting it already: [Cufon text-stroke feature request](http://github.com/sorccu/cufon/issues#issue/5). [sIFR](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/) doesn't seem to support stroke/outlines either..

Comment: The reason only webkit supports it is because webkit made it up and there is no such thing in CSS3.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can do it using text-shadows in Cufon.

`Cufon.replace("h2", {hover:'true', textShadow: "#ff0000 1px 1px, #ff0000 -1px -1px"});`

Just use two text-shadows and place them diagonally opposite of each other.

Comment: looks pretty bad, but probably depends on font

Answer (score 0):

Ahha! Discovered [FLIR](http://facelift.mawhorter.net/) shortly after posting this question.

Here is the text-stroke effect example: http://facelift.mawhorter.net/doc/plugins-quickeffects

The quickeffects plugin is included in the [download](http://facelift.mawhorter.net/download/).

A nice drupal module as well for those who are interested: http://drupal.org/project/flir

Comment: The link to `FLIR` is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Drupal solution.  I did the following with a custom module and cufon module installed as a dependency.

Setup cufon as normal then add a submodule as follows:

cbi_cufon.module

```
<?php
// $Id$

/**
 * Implementation of hook_init().
 *
 * Just adding in our cufon definitions.
 */
function cbi_cufon_init() {
  $settings = array(
    array(
      'selector' => '#site-slogan',
      'options' => array(
        'fontFamily' => 'Fontname', // Likely need to change this to match yours or remove this line completely if you will have only one cufon font
        'textShadow' => '1px 0px #FFFFFF, 0px 1px #FFFFFF, -1px 0px #FFFFFF, 0px -1px #FFFFFF, 2px 2px #DDDDDD',
      ),
    ),
  );
  drupal_add_js(array('cufonSelectors' => $settings), 'setting');
}
```

cbi_cufon.info

```
;$Id$
name = Cufon font definitions
description = Adds font definitions for CBI.
core = 6.x
version = VERSION
dependencies[] = cufon
```

If this doesn't help the op, I hope it helps someone else.  Additionally, I did try the flir module and had unpredic

Comment: hi,

@nicholas.alipaz

Does your module allow to modify the textShadow on hover ?
If yes, can you show the syntax for that ?

Thanks for your work